# jQuery Date/Time Picker not serializing via .serialize())

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the jQuery Date/Time picker [show here](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/) and I have it in a form. When the submit button is pressed I serialize the form and save the serialization to localStorage.

i.e.

```
localStorage.form_data = $('myform').serialize();
```

Some of my form data shows up in the serialized string except for my form inputs that use the jQuery Date/Time picker, anyone know why? Or if there's a work around..

I can get around it using my own serialize method but I'm curious about when the .serialize() & .serializeArray() breaks down...

Comment: Please show the HTML for the form, and any relevant javascript.

Answer (score 3):

For a form element's value to be included in the serialized string, the element must have a name attribute. Values from checkboxes and radio buttons (inputs of type "radio" or "checkbox") are included only if they are checked. Data from file select elements is not serialized.

documentation - http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

NOTE - ensure that all elements have a name attribute